# Can this parsing problem be nicely done with awk?

Tags: bash, awk, nested, brackets

I am trying to process a whitelist in bash, but I would like to process it with awk.
The whitelist.txt has a format like
`module:function(arguments)`
and in one line multiple arguments or multiple functions can be specified, in a comma-separated list format.
Multiple functions can be encased in-between square brackets, while arguments are encased in-between round brackets, like this:
`some_module_name:[func1(arg1,arg2),func2]`
Arguments can be encased in-between double quotes if they have white spaces, like this:
`some_module:[function-alpha(arg1,"argument 2 has spaces"),function-beta]`

On the right-end of any line there can be some flags, like `offline_install=true`, `paralell_run=true` and so on (separated by white spaces). Those will be stored separately in an array afterwards.

How can I use awk to transform the input file format:

```
module1:function1(alpha,beta),function2 offline_install=true paralell_run=true
module2:[function-alpha(arg1,"argument 2 is inside quotes",arg3),function-beta]
```

into the output file format:

```
module1:function1(alpha)
module1:function1(beta)
module1:function2
module2:function-alpha(arg1)
module2:function-alpha("argument 2 is inside quotes")
module2:function-alpha(arg3)
module2:function-beta
```

Specifically, I want to:

- Expand each comma-separated list inside the square brackets [] into separate lines, while keeping the corresponding module and function name at the beginning of each line.
- For each argument inside round brackets (), print it on a separate line along with the corresponding module and function name at the beginning of each line.
- Preserve any quoted arguments with spaces inside the quotes.

Here's another example, if it helps.
whitelist.txt:

```
control_service:(stop=apache,"disable=apache (everywhere)")
database:add_redo_log_groups
database:check_data_consistency paralell_run=true
sas_certificate
p/a/g/config.sh:[function1(status,"start firewall [1]","stop [all] firewall"),func2] offline_install=true paralell_run=true
control_server:stop,disable
database:kill_sessions paralell_run=true
my_module
my_module:[func1,func2]
```

output_file.txt

```
control_service:(stop=apache)
control_service:("disable=apache (everywhere)")
database:add_redo_log_groups
database:check_data_consistency paralell_run=true
sas_certificate
p/a/g/config.sh:function1(status) offline_install=true paralell_run=true
p/a/g/config.sh:function1("start firewall [1]") offline_install=true paralell_run=true
p/a/g/config.sh:function1("stop [all] firewall") offline_install=true paralell_run=true
p/a/g/config.sh:func2 offline_install=true paralell_run=true
control_server:stop
control_server:disable
database:kill_sessions paralell_run=true
my_module
my_module:func1
my_module:func2
```

I've tried different approaches, but so far, I have not been able to generate the correct output. Any help with the awk script would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your quoted strings can include commas, colons, parens, etc., this gets a little hairy. How much can you assume?

Comment: in the 2nd set of samples you show variable assigments being copied to the output, but you don't show this same behavior (for variable assignments) in the 1st set of samples; please update the question to either a) show consistent use of variable assignments or b) explain the differences (re: variable assignments) between the two samples

Comment: *`I've tried different approaches`* - please update the question with some of your 'approaches'

Comment: how are these lists generated? how are they used? I'm wondering if there may already be some tools available for parsing this particular format ...

Comment: @PaulHodges - the quoted strings can include commas, colons, parens - only another set of double quoted strings it can't. I know it is a little "hairy" - I got some problems parsing those...

Comment: @markp-fuso - if by "variable assigments" you mean those "paralell_run=true" and "offline_install=true", then, yes, those are some sort of "variable assignments" or you can consider them just as a set of attributes. I'm thinking to store all of those (separated by space) in a special array for each module, anyway (as they will be given as arguments for the actual installer of that module).

Comment: `'variable assignments'` ... `'attribute=value'` pairs ... they are not presented consistently in the two samples; please update the samples or update the description to explain the inconsistencies

Comment: Seems pretty doable (albeit a little involved) when using GNU `awk`'s `FPAT`/`patsplit`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Comment: @Socowi - I am delving into the patsplit awk function and - indeed, patsplit really simplifies the problem, it seems :) . Thanks for the hint! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start showing you how to encode/decode the problematic characters inside the quoted strings so you can then identify and/or split on those characters outside the quoted strings:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    print "---------"
    printf "$0 = %s\n", $0

    module = gensub(/:.*/,"",1,$0)
    fns_args = substr($0,length(module)+2)

    printf "module = %s\n",  module
    printf "raw fns_args = %s\n", fns_args

    encoded_fns_args = encode(fns_args)

    printf "encoded fns_args = %s\n", encoded_fns_args

    if ( match(encoded_fns_args,/\[(.*)]\s*(.*)/,a) ) {
        encoded_args = a[2]
        decoded_args = decode(encoded_args)
        printf "decoded_args = %s\n", decoded_args

        n = split(a[1],encoded_fns,/,/)
        for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
            encoded_fn = encoded_fns[i]
            decoded_fn = decode(encoded_fn)
            printf "decoded_fn = %s\n", decoded_fn
        }
    }
}

function encode(str,    a) {
    gsub(/[@]/,"@A",str)
    while ( match(str,/([^"]*)("[^"]*")(.*)/,a) ) {
        gsub(/[[]/,"@B",a[2])
        gsub(/[]]/,"@C",a[2])
        gsub(/[(]/,"@D",a[2])
        gsub(/[)]/,"@E",a[2])
        gsub(/[,]/,"@F",a[2])
        gsub(/["]/,"@G",a[2])
        str = a[1] a[2] a[3]
    }
    return str
}

function decode(str) {
    gsub(/@G/,"\"",str)
    gsub(/@F/,",",str)
    gsub(/@E/,")",str)
    gsub(/@D/,"(",str)
    gsub(/@C/,"]",str)
    gsub(/@B/,"[",str)
    gsub(/@A/,"@",str)
    return str
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk whitelist.txt
---------
$0 = control_service:(stop=apache,"disable=apache (everywhere)")
module = control_service
raw fns_args = (stop=apache,"disable=apache (everywhere)")
encoded fns_args = (stop=apache,@Gdisable=apache @Deverywhere@E@G)
---------
$0 = database:add_redo_log_groups
module = database
raw fns_args = add_redo_log_groups
encoded fns_args = add_redo_log_groups
---------
$0 = database:check_data_consistency paralell_run=true
module = database
raw fns_args = check_data_consistency paralell_run=true
encoded fns_args = check_data_consistency paralell_run=true
---------
$0 = sas_certificate
module = sas_certificate
raw fns_args =
encoded fns_args =
---------
$0 = p/a/g/config.sh:[function1(status,"start firewall [1]","stop [all] firewall"),func2] offline_install=true paralell_run=true
module = p/a/g/config.sh
raw fns_args = [function1(status,"start firewall [1]","stop [all] firewall"),func2] offline_install=true paralell_run=true
encoded fns_args = [function1(status,@Gstart firewall @B1@C@G,@Gstop @Ball@C firewall@G),func2] offline_install=true paralell_run=true
decoded_args = offline_install=true paralell_run=true
decoded_fn = function1(status
decoded_fn = "start firewall [1]"
decoded_fn = "stop [all] firewall")
decoded_fn = func2
---------
$0 = control_server:stop,disable
module = control_server
raw fns_args = stop,disable
encoded fns_args = stop,disable
---------
$0 = database:kill_sessions paralell_run=true
module = database
raw fns_args = kill_sessions paralell_run=true
encoded fns_args = kill_sessions paralell_run=true
---------
$0 = my_module
module = my_module
raw fns_args =
encoded fns_args =
---------
$0 = my_module:[func1,func2]
module = my_module
raw fns_args = [func1,func2]
encoded fns_args = [func1,func2]
decoded_args =
decoded_fn = func1
decoded_fn = func2
```

The above uses GNU awk for various extensions and is not intended to be the full script you need, it's just a [big] start showing you a way to solve the problem.

Comment: I like your answer very much - it is clear what each step is and it's quite easy to debug, thanks! :)
Only that - for some reason I don't understand yet - there seems to be a problem with the round brackets?... They seem to not get replaced by @D and @E - for some reason?...

Comment: I only wrote it to replace problematic chars inside quoted strings - you don't have any round brackets inside your quoted strings. I'm showing you how to do encodeing/decoding of problematic chars in specific contexts (quoted strings), how to do it inside quoted strings, how to isolate text inside square quotes, and how to then split on commas - you still have work to properly isolate the functions within the square brackets rather than just splitting on all commas, and apply those techniques I showed you to the function args inside the round brackets, etc.